# Sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ with $a_j\in\lbrace 1,2,\ldots,j\rbrace$ such that almost all $\sum_{j=1}^na_j\cdot j!$ are prime-numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

*Are there prime-numbers having infinite left-expansions of non-zero coefficients in the factorial number system involving only prime numbers?*

The question is really in the title : Is there an infinite
sequence of strictly positive integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots$
with $a_i\leq i$ such that $n\longmapsto \sum_{j=1}^n a_jj!$
is prime except for a finite number of values.

A heuristical argument seems to indicate that the
answer can easily go either way :

A finite sequence $a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}$ with $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_jj!$ prime can be extended in $n$
different ways to a number $N(a_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_jj!$ with $a_n\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
Such a number $N(a_n)$ is roughly of size $n!$
and a random number of this size is prime with
probability $1/\log(n!)$ which is roughly $1/(n((\log n)-1))$.
Such a number $N(a_n)$ is however not completely
random since it cannot have prime-factors $\leq n$. This improves
the odds for primeness of $N(a_n)$ by something like $1+c\log\log n$
(for some constant $c$).

Experimentally, starting with $5=1\cdot 1!+2\cdot 2!$,
there seems to be a very large (perhaps infinite) 'extension-tree'
(defined in an obvious way: $5$ is followed by the primes $11=5+1\cdot 3!,17=5+2\cdot 3!$ and $23=5+3\cdot 3!$) rooted at $5$ and containing only prime numbers.

A few remarks: The answer is clearly yes without the restriction $a_i>0$.

I expect that the answer is 'no' if one replaces the factorial
number system with expansions in base $b\geq 2$. (In base $2$,
the answer is obviously 'no', in other bases this is probably not
trivial but heuristically, the corresponding 'prime-trees' should
die off).

Last remark: It would be surprising that nobody has asked this question (or a very similar one) before.

Comment: In fixed bases see [A103443](https://oeis.org/A103443).

Comment: How far did your experiments go? My breadth-first search indicates an average branching factor of about $e$ up to $n=20$, where it ran into space issues. My depth-first search, however, has yet to get past $n=49$, where it has found over 300000 leaves.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I restarted sometimes from some higher vertex in order to avoid space issues. I did this a few times and it started always a seemingly large tree. But thanks for your experimentations. The average branching factor of about $e$ looks interesting.

Comment: That's in the levels near the root. Further from the root I'm still hitting a brick wall. At $n \in \{43,44,45,47,48\}$ I'm seeing an average branching factor of $1$, at $n = 46$ an average branching factor of $2$, and at $n=49$ an average branching factor of $0$ (with 3.35 million nodes processed at $n=49$).

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's interesting! Could it be finite?

Comment: There certainly seems to be something interesting going on. If I calculate correctly, with the compensation for coprimality with small primes the expected branching factor should be above 2 until a threshold slightly past $n = 10000$.